# oauth2 gem, validating oauth token received in request header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, auth0

I am using the oauth2 gem and I can get a token from auth0 and make post requests successfully. However, I can't work out what to do when the other party makes a post request to my application. Presumably, I get a token in the request header but how do I validate it?

Answer (score 0):

Having looked at the source I don't think the oauth2 gem helps here, but I found out how to do it here  https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/rails/01-authorization